# How to compare value of two columns then create a third/new data frame depending on the result

Tags: r, join, filter, conditional-statements

I have two columns, one name column and then a text column. I want to find the linking matches between the name columns that share the same text in the text column and create a third column with that name (the result could also just be a new data frame). Also, if you could tell me what this type of transform would be called - it might be easier for me to search for similar examples (or other users). I have tried to do some self joins and filtering and have not had much luck.

```r
Name <- c("John","Sally","Alex", "Sarah", "Joe", "Sue")
Status <- c('A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A')
df <- data.frame(Name,Status)
```

What I have:

```r
Name  Status
John    A           
Sally   B           
Alex    A           
Sarah   B           
Joe     C           
Sue     A
```

This is the result I want:

```r
Column 1      Column 2   Column 3
   John          A        Alex   
   John          A        Sue 
   Sally         B        Sarah
   Joe           C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a dplyr full-join:

```r
library(dplyr)
full_join(df, df, by = "Status") %>%
  group_by(Status) %>%
  mutate(Name.y = if_else(Name.x == Name.y & n() == 1, Name.y[NA], Name.y)) %>%
  filter(is.na(Name.y) | Name.x < Name.y) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#   Name.x Status Name.y
#   <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
# 1 John   A      Sue   
# 2 Sally  B      Sarah 
# 3 Alex   A      John  
# 4 Alex   A      Sue   
# 5 Joe    C      NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Network analysis might be relevant here, using *igraph* package we can find the *memebership*.

For example, we can see "John", "Sue" and "Alex" are all connected to each other via status "A".

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
plot(g)

components(g)$membership
# John Sally  Alex Sarah   Joe   Sue     A     B     C 
#    1     2     1     2     3     1     1     2     3
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
# split based on duplicates in the Status-column
dt1 <- df[!duplicated(Status), ]
dt2 <- df[duplicated(Status), ]
# join 
final <- dt2[dt1, on = .(Status)]

# the following lines are for column-order and -naming only
setcolorder(final, c(3,2,1))
setnames(final, c("col1", "col2", "col3"))


    col1 col2  col3
1:  John    A  Alex
2:  John    A   Sue
3: Sally    B Sarah
4:   Joe    C  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) dplyr** For each Status we create 3 columns consisting of the Name and Status columns of the first row and Name column of the other rows or NA if no other rows.

```
library(dplyr) # version 1.1.0 or later
df %>%
  reframe(col1 = first(Name), 
          col2 = first(Status), 
          col3 = if (n() == 1) NA else tail(Name, -1), .by = Status) %>%
  select(-Status)
```

giving:

```
   col1 col2  col3
1  John    A  Alex
2  John    A   Sue
3 Sally    B Sarah
4   Joe    C  <NA>
```

**2) base R** This uses base R to perform a left join:

```
merge(subset(df, !duplicated(Status)),
      subset(df, duplicated(Status)), all.x = TRUE, by = "Status")
```

giving

```
  Status Name.x Name.y
1      A   John   Alex
2      A   John    Sue
3      B  Sally  Sarah
4      C    Joe   <NA>
```